# cumulocity's rasberrypi's "c8y-agent.sh" file not working

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, cumulocity

I am trying to connect my cumulocity-rpi-agent to cumulocity so that I can have two options either accept or cancel. But this options will be available only when i execute `sh c8y-agent-debug.sh`  this file using `sh` command. I followed below steps

```
1) wget http://resources.cumulocity.com/examples/cumulocity-rpi-agent-latest.deb
2) sudo dpkg -i cumulocity-rpi-agent-latest.deb
```

And:

```
login as: pi
pi@raspberrypi.mshome.net's password:
...

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd /usr/share/
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/share $ cd cu
cumulocity-rpi-agent/ cups/
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/share $ cd cumulocity-rpi-agent/
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/share/cumulocity-rpi-agent $ sh c8y-agent.sh
^C
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/share/cumulocity-rpi-agent $ sudo nano
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/share/cumulocity-rpi-agent
```

And:

```
 #!/bin/sh
    (
    while true
    do
      echo "Running the Cumulocity Linux Agent..."
      java -cp 'cfg/*:lib/*' -Dlogback.configurationFile=cfg/logback.xml c8y.lx.age$
      sleep 1
    done
    ) 2>&1 | logger
```

this is `c8y-agent-debug.sh script` I execute this file using `sh c8y-agent-debug.sh` or `bash c8y-agent-debug.sh` but executing the file not event echo statement.

Do i need to set anything related to java. Java is already installed. Is there any additional setting required for that `java -cp` command. Java is installed on `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/` on this path. This is on linux. `javac` and `java` commands are working fine

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question exactly, but here's some information: The agent is a background service and runs directly after installation. If it is not running (try "ps"), there's probably an issue with the configuration. In that case, you can find out about it by looking into the syslog. It does not print anything to the console, since it runs in the background.

Comment: i am confused about debug.I don't know how to debug it does not show any error on terminal where the syslog is located